# ROR with ideone-api: wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm completely new to rails and I'm using [ideone-ruby-api](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ideone-ruby-api/2.1.2) to build a code evaluator.
However, I can't get it to run despite following the documentation as this error pops up:

**ArgumentError in CodeEvalController#create**

**wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)**

**Extracted source (around line #18):**

```
18     $instance = Ideone.new('username','password')
19     assert_not_nil($instance)
```

Here's the complete controller.rb file I'm using:

```
1 require 'rubygems'
2 require 'bundler'
3 require 'ideone'
4
5 class CodeEvalController < ApplicationController
6
7   def index
8     @message = Sourcecode.first.body
9   end
10
11  def create
12     @artifact = Sourcecode.first
13     if params[:reset_button]
14       @artifact.update_attributes(body: "Hello World")
15     else
16       @artifact.update_attributes(body: params[:code][:body])
17     end
18     $instance = Ideone.new('username','password')
19     assert_not_nil($instance)
20     redirect_to code_eval_index_path(@artifact)
21  end
22 end
```

The problem seems with the *Ideone.new* method and the number of arguments that it takes. The [doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ideone-ruby-api/2.1.2) suggests it takes in a username and a password, which is exactly what I am doing, and yet the error says wrong number of arguments. 
I have already specified *gem 'ideone-ruby-api'* in the Gemfile and done a *bundle install*. Can anyone help me debug this issue?

Comment: what ruby version are you using?

Comment: does  @artifact consist of body only?